# Syspro Soap API exception: Server was unable to process request. ---> Operator '{blank}' not found

Tags: php, api, exception, soap

Thanks in advance.
In this week i have received requirement form client to integrate syspro API in our project. He has given me details of api but as syspro have less documentation, I am facing many issues. So I have created a simple test file shown bellow to create soap client call but it is throwing exception shown bellow code. I am not getting that I have passed wrong parameters or I have wrong credentials.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

try{

    $opts = array(
            'http' => array(
                'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
                ),
            'ssl' => array(
            // set some SSL/TLS specific options
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $client = new SoapClient('https://syspro.domain.com/SYSPROWebServices/utilities.asmx?WSDL',
                             array('stream_context' => $context,
                                   'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

    // client has given me only Operator and CompanyId but passwords for both are blank as client said
    $Operator = 'operator given by client';
    $OperatorPassword = '';
    $CompanyId = 'operator given by client';
    $CompanyPassword = '';
    $LanguageCode = 'ENGLISH_US';
    $LogLevel = 'ldDebug';
    $EncoreInstance = 'EncoreInstance_0';
    $XMLIn = '';

    $result = $client->Logon($Operator,$OperatorPassword,$CompanyId,$CompanyPassword,$LanguageCode,$LogLevel,$EncoreInstance,$XMLIn);

} catch(Exception $e){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($client);
}
```

Above call generating bellow error:

```
SoapClient Object
(
    [_stream_context] => Resource id #1
    [_soap_version] => 1
    [sdl] => Resource id #3
    [httpsocket] => Resource id #4
    [_use_proxy] => 0
    [httpurl] => Resource id #5
    [__soap_fault] => SoapFault Object
        (
            [message:protected] => Server was unable to process request. ---> Operator '{blank}' not found
            [string:Exception:private] => 
            [code:protected] => 0
            [file:protected] => /var/sites/domain/dev38/test.php
            [line:protected] => 33
            [trace:Exception:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => /var/sites/domain/dev38/test.php
                            [line] => 33
                            [function] => __call
                            [class] => SoapClient
                            [type] => ->
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Logon
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Operator given by client
                                            [1] => 
                                            [2] => CompanyId given by client
                                            [3] => 
                                            [4] => ENGLISH_US
                                            [5] => ldDebug
                                            [6] => EncoreInstance_0
                                            [7] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => /var/sites/domain/dev38/test.php
                            [line] => 33
                            [function] => Logon
                            [class] => SoapClient
                            [type] => ->
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Operator given by client
                                    [1] => 
                                    [2] => CompanyId given by client
                                    [3] => 
                                    [4] => ENGLISH_US
                                    [5] => ldDebug
                                    [6] => EncoreInstance_0
                                    [7] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [previous:Exception:private] => 
            [faultstring] => Server was unable to process request. ---> Operator '{blank}' not found
            [faultcode] => soap:Server
            [detail] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use SYSPRO Web Services - depending on the version of SYSPRO that is being integrated with it may be better/easier to integrate using our e.net Communications Service (via WCF).

There is information available regarding both of these on the [InfoZone](http://infozone.syspro.com/support) and you can also post and ask questions on the [SYSPRO Forums](http://forums.syspro.com) regarding the product and any issues you may be having.

Comment: Thanks Cris for your input, I'll check the links which you shared and I will come back with results.